# How to determine possible solutions for a time dep. Schrödinger equation for a particle in a box?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

For a particle of mass $m$ in a box of width $L$, to be more exact, with a uniform potential energy of  between two infinitely high barriers, one at position  and the other at position, what are the nature of solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions will be in the form $$\Psi(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)e^{\frac{-iE_n t}{\hbar}}$$

hence for instance, $$\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi z}{L}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{2\pi z}{L}\right)\right)\exp\left(-i\frac{\pi^2\hbar}{2mL^2}t\right)$$

can not be the solution as as the time dependancy is wrong for the second term in the spatial component, however the first term is correctly shows time dependence.

Furthermore, $$\sqrt{\frac{2}{3L}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi z}{L}\right)\exp\left(-i\frac{\pi^2\hbar}{2mL^2}t\right)+\sqrt{\frac{2}{3L}}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi z}{L}\right)\exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi^2\hbar}{mL^2}t\right)-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3L}}\sin\left(\frac{3\pi z}{L}\right)\exp\left(-i\frac{9\pi^2\hbar}{2mL^2}t\right)$$

is a solution. Even though it looks complicated and difficult to see, an observation would indicate it is a linear superposition of solutions for $n=1$, $n=2$ and for $n=3$. Looking at long solutions and thinking it as a whole might cause confusion, separating the solution to three different liner solutions and treating the whole solution as a linear superposition would help noticing the validity of the solution.