# About the nature of particle in a box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability

Suppose we have a particle in a box, which indicates an infinitely deep potential well and we have our particle in an unequal superposition of the first two energy states, which we can write as
$$a\Psi _{1}(z,t) + b\Psi _{2}(z,t)$$
Is the probability distribution of such a system constant in time? Or is it constant in certain places in the box?

Comment: Since this is a homework-like question, you shouldn’t expect a complete answer. Homework-like questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Related: [How to determine possible solutions for a time dep. Schrödinger equation for a particle in a box?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/732054/how-to-determine-possible-solutions-for-a-time-dep-schrödinger-equation-for-a-p)

Comment: It is not related. That is concerning the nature of solutions, this is about the probability density. Moreover, that was 6 days ago, where I was fairly new here and if you can see, the question was edited by me to try to correct it. As I was fairly new I didn't know about the homework like policy here. That was a homework question as I was asking a question with literal values, you can see that with the edit history of the question. This does not relate to that at all.

Comment: One of the fundamental postulates of QM is that for any normalized wavefunction $\Psi$ the correspondng probability density is  $|\Psi|^2$.

Comment: I know that actually, but what about for uneven superpositions?

Comment: *Any normalized wavefunction*. That includes your superposition as long as $a$ and $b$ make it normalized.

Comment: Note: For some superpositions, the probability density can be constant in time at other locations than the edges. The general argument in Miguel’s answer won’t tell you where they are, but an explicit calculation will.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> our particle in an unequal superposition of the first two energy states, which we can write as $$a\Psi _{1}(z,t) + b\Psi _{2}(z,t)$$

The space and time dependence of the stationary states is:
$$
\Psi_n(z, t) = e^{-i E_n t/\hbar} \phi_n(z)\;,
$$
where
$$
E_n = \frac{\hbar^2 \pi^2 n^2}{2mL^2}
$$
and
$$
\phi_n(z) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin(\frac{n\pi z}{L})\;,
$$
for a box from $0$ to $L$.

> Is the probability distribution of such a system constant in time? Or is it constant in certain places in the box?

The probability density is:
$$
|a\Phi_1 + b\Phi_2|^2 = |a|^2|\phi_1(z)|^2 + |b|^2|\phi_2(z)|^2
+\phi_1(z)\phi_2(z)\left(ab^* e^{i\Delta t} + a^*b e^{-i\Delta t}\right)\;,\tag{1}
$$
where $\Delta = (E_2 - E_1)/\hbar$.

As seen in Eq (1) above, the first two terms are constant in time, but the last term (proportional to $\phi_1\phi_2$) changes with time.

There is one point inside the box where the probability density is constant in time. The probability density is also constant (and equal to zero) at the boundaries.

Comment: While all of what you said is accurate and correct I think this answer gives too many details of the eigenvectors and eigenvalues that are not needed at all to reason about the questions being asked. I think a response based solely on the postulates is more helpful as it will apply equally well to any potential not just the infinite square well.

Comment: @MiguelGarcia  The only way to know everywhere the probability density is constant in time is to know the spatial dependence of the eigenfunctions.

Comment: @Ghoster I know but as given the answer seems to imply that the time dependence is a matter of the actual form of the wavefunction. Everything should be reasoned directly from the axioms up to the point where it is asked if the wave function has a fixed point only then should one inspect the actual eigenfunctions. By the way the fixed point is just midpoint in the box.

Answer (score 2):

An eigenstate of the Hamiltonian operator is stationary (this is rather a trivial result since the operator that generates time evolution according to Schrodinger picture is basically the Hamiltonian, however make sure to look at it on a textbook). Your state is not an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian therefore (**most likely**) it will not be stationary i.e. it will change as time goes on (please note the words in bold, since this is not a logical consequence). The wavefunction will be zero at each of the edges since probability (the modulus squared of the wavefunction) cannot "leak out" an infinite well and must be continuous as well. You can gain some intuition and get some understanding with this simulations:

https://learncheme.com/simulations/physical-chemistry/particle-in-a-box-1/

To make the point rigorous lets write some math:
$$\Psi(t_0)=a\psi_1e^{\frac{-iE_1t_0}{\hbar}}+b\psi_2e^{\frac{-iE_2t_0}{\hbar}}.$$
Since the evolution operator is given by $U(t,t_0)=e^\frac{-iH(t-t_0)}{\hbar}$, at some later time $t$ the wavefunction will be
$$\Psi(t)=U(t,t_0)\Psi(t_0)=a\psi_1e^{\frac{-iE_1t}{\hbar}}+b\psi_2e^{\frac{-iE_2t}{\hbar}},$$
where we used the fact that: $U(t,t_0)\psi_n=\psi_ne^\frac{-iE_n(t-t_0)}{\hbar}$.

Since $E_1 \neq E_2$ a common phase factor cannot be factored out, and so clearly $\Psi(t) \neq \Psi(t_0)$, and the probability density function will pick up an oscillating cross term (the frequency of oscillation being the energy difference of the two eigenstates), so it is non constant in time.
The important point to notice is that it was not necessary to solve the Schrödinger equation; we could argue based directly on the postulates of quantum mechanics.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the source specifically!

Comment: The problem you are looking at is the (1 dimensional) infinite square well, it will be explained in any book on quantum mechanics so it is a matter of taste. My personal favourites are Bransden & Joachain on the one hand and Shankar but there are many many book on the topic differing mostly on style and mathematical sophistication. I suggest you take a look at the most cited ones and pick the one or two titles that suits you best.